# How to use a handler from settings for a non-Django log

Tags: python, django, logging, suds

In my Django project, I'm using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/), which logs to a predetermined log (suds.client) and doesn't let me configure a different log for its messages.  I'm trying to get around this by adding one of the handlers I have defined in settings.py.  In my code that uses suds:

```
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    suds_logger = logging.getLogger('suds.client')
    suds_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    suds_logger.addHandler('my_handler')
    suds_logger.propagate = False
```

This is obviously incorrect (because I'm just passing the string naming the handler and not the handler itself) and results in this error:

`ERROR:my_handler:'str' object has no attribute 'level'`

So, it seems like all I have to do is correctly use the 'my_handler' handler from settings and I should be good to go.  So, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: why you pass string 'my_handler' as argument?

Comment: @eri that is exactly what I'm asking: how do I pass in an existing Django handler correctly?

Comment: i think this function expects some kind of object.